# Discrepancy between Event Log taken from Powershell and with Event Log Viewer

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, windows-event-log, eventviewer

Domain Controller OS - Window Server 2008 R2

Please see the First PrintScreen attached (Powershell.png). with the help of Powershell command I am trying to check the event Log of my DC. Please note the Red Rectangle Colour Box. Failure Reason: %%2313 "

[image]

But the same log if i check from Event Viewer ( Second Print-Screen Attached - EventViewer.png ) the same Event ID, here it Clearly shows the "Failure Reason: Unknown user name or bad Password"

[image]

Why with Powershell the same event id shows Failure reason with some syntax and in Event Viewer log of windows, it display correct?

Comment: We typically call events like these "bugs".

Comment: Thanks Micheal Hampton for your comment.So,how should i correct this problem? Because with the help of Powershell i get mail for the event id and in mail we are unable to know the real reason.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows Vista and later you should use Get-WinEvent as it can read the extended event data more of the time

For more detail about this command you can use -? symbol. 
or 
Refer to this article
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849682.aspx